# XMPP chat in Android

Tags: java, android, xmpp, ejabberd

This is my Roster class.

```
public class RosterList extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Variables var = new Variables();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.roster);

    Roster roster = var.connection.getRoster();
    Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
    TextView tv;

    for (RosterEntry r : entries) {
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rosterString);
        tv.append(r.getUser().toString()+ "\n");
    }
  }
}
```

I have created a separate class for hold variables which is `Variables`. There i have created my `XMPPConnection`-variable and others. But there are some runtime errors in this code.

Error occurs when `roster`-object is created. How can i access the `XMPPConnection` for this class? Why can't i create an instance of the Variables class and access connection variable ?

Comment: Need stack trace or code for variables class. But most likely its because you are statically initializing the variables class. not a good idea for internet accessing classes.

Comment: This is the basic Variable class.
    public class Variables {
 
 XMPPConnection connection;
 ConnectionConfiguration config;

}

This problem happens only when creating Roster. For Login no error :(

Comment: You are connecting b4 getting roster correct?

Comment: yah.. its ok now with static variables :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static variables solved the problem. :)